# How to find local truncation error in Forward Euler Method without knowing the actual value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eulers-method, truncation-error

In my high school project, I am solving differential equations using the forward Euler numerical method and this is because the equations were too hard to solve analytically.

To find the local error in the approximation. Generally, you would take the actual value and subtract the approximate value and take the modulus. However,  I don't know what the actual value is. But I have read that the local error is proportional to the step size squared and in my paper, the step size is 1.

$|T_i|≤\frac{Mh^2}{2}$

However, I dont know what the constant M means or the steps to calculate the constant.

These are the differential equations that I am working with.
Note:
All symbols that are not functions of t are constants.

\begin{equation}
\frac{dS}{dt} = \Lambda - \mu S(t) - \beta S(t) \frac{I(t)}{N(t)} -  \zeta \lambda S(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{dE}{dt} = \beta S(t) \frac{I(t)}{N(t)} + \beta V(t) \frac{I(t)}{N(t)} -  (\mu + \epsilon) E(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{dI}{dt} = \epsilon E(t) - (\gamma + \mu + \alpha) I(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{dR}{dt} = \gamma I(t) + \zeta V(t) - \mu R(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{dV}{dt} = \zeta \lambda S(t) - \beta V(t) \frac{I(t)}{N(t)} -  \zeta V(t) - \mu V(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{dD}{dt} = \alpha I(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{dN}{dt} = \frac{dS}{dt} + \frac{dE}{dt} + \frac{dI}{dt} + \frac{dR}{dt} + \frac{dV}{dt} + \frac{dD}{dt}
\end{equation}

Comment: Compute the same but with double the step size. Then apply Richardson extrapolation to get an error estimate. The idea is to make the solution in a controlled way better or worse and apply the local or global error model to get a better estimate for the exact solution and thus for the error.

Comment: Do you know any websites or papers to where I can read further about this, thank you.

Comment: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/math/vble.pdf has a nice overview of variable-step implementations of low-order methods from Euler to Fehlberg (not RKF45, one order lower).